Linker problems with Visual Studio 2022 using C
I have some strange and inconsistent behavior with Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 10 platform when trying to link a global variable in C.
In a previous solution I have the following header file "main.h":
#include <stdio.h>

// Various other includes, prototypes defines etc.

extern FILE* logFp; // Which is the last statement in the file.

In the main file in "main.c" I have the code:
#include "main.h"

FILE* logFp;

int main(void) {

  errno_t fileErr = 0;
  char logFn[FNAME_LEN] = { 0 };
  printf("Type the output log filename:                                 ");
  scanf_s("%s", logFn, FNAME_LEN);
  fileErr = fopen_s(&logFp, logFn, "w");

  // Many other statements that call functions in other files.

  fclose(logFp);
  return 0;

}

In the solution there are several source files in C, with each containing several functions. The first line in each file starts with the include followed by the functions in the form:
#include "main.h"

functionA(...) {

  // ...

}

functionB(...) {

  // ...

}

// Etc.

This all compiles and links correctly in debug mode, then executes correctly. I then created a new solution where I copied over all the .h and .c files without any significant modifications, and I plan to make some changes. However, although the code compiles correctly, on linking I get a whole load of errors. The first two are:
1>x64\Debug\main.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>stegan-functions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol logFp

followed by several errors similar to the last for each of the files that contain
logFp.
I looked up the warning LNK4042, but that code is not listed at the link when you click on it. This is obviously related to why logFp causes the errors. What I do not understand at all is why in the old version of the solution this worked, but now I get these errors, although as yet no significant changes have been made. Is this something to do with how the linker with Visual Studio is configured? I looked at the linker options, and they appear to be the same for the old and new solutions. Someone must have had problems similar to these, so would appreciate some help, as I am stuck. Until this can be fixed, I cannot make any changes to the new solution.

Make sure you haven't mixed up the contents of main.h and main.c in the copying process. "object specified more than once", I suppose, means that your solution contains more than one definition of an object. The build output should tell you which object that is which should give you a clue where to look.

If I comment out "FILE* logFp;" at the beginning of main.c just before the main method, I get the same errors.

This also applies if I comment out all the code in main(void) except for return 0 at the end.

Are you sure the extern is present in the header?

Yes, "extern FILE* logFp;" is the last line in the header.

Would uninstalling Visual Studio 2022, rebooting my computer, then re-installing Visual Studio work? I want to avoid this if possible, as I have it configured for C/C++, together with the clases for GUIs.

Try adding guards in your main.h (the #ifndef .. #define ..#endif thing).

Please post a [mcve]. Meaning you start with the solution that has the proble, and then you remove code incrementally until the problem disappears. This requires some work for you to do, but in the process you might very well find out yourself what the problem is.

@csharp - The Visual Studio installer has a Repair option that will add back any files you might have accidentally deleted or detroyed. I have hardly ever heard about a full reinstall making a difference. The odds are at least 100:1 that there is something odd in your files, not in the compiler.

It appears that there might be a problem with Visual Studio 2022. I created a new project with just the code in "main.h" as:
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>


// === Global ===
extern FILE* logFp;

Then in "main.c" I put in the following test code:
#include "main.h"

FILE* logFp;

int main(void) {

  printf("Hello World!\n");

  // Handle log file.
  errno_t fileErr = 0;
  char logFn[FNAME_LEN] = { 0 };
  printf("Type the output log filename:                                 ");
  scanf_s("%s", logFn, FNAME_LEN);
  fileErr = fopen_s(&logFp, logFn, "w");

  fprintf(logFp, "Now in log file\n");

  fclose(logFp);
  return 0;
}

which compiled and linked, then produced the test output correctly.
My application has nearly 100 function organized in 13 source files, not including "main.c", and the function prototypes are all in "main.h", with each set of prototypes below a comment with the name of the file that contains the relevant functions, and at the top of each file is a short comment that should match the comment above the set of prototypes. This is in order reduce the chance of copying over the wrong files, but even if I did, which was the case, it makes checking much easier.
As I copied over the files I attempted to compile the application several times. There were some link errors before all the files were copied over, and a few times I copied over duplicate code to the wrong file. These errors were fixed, then after replacing the test code in "main.c" by the full code from the previous solution, all the files compiled and linked correctly, and ran correctly. Incidentally, each source file other than "main.c" just has the first line of code with #include "main.h".
I looked again at the previous solution, and all the files are correct, but continue to get the errors I mentioned before, even after doing rebuild solutions and clean solutions several times. Unless I have missed something, somehow an error when first attempting to compile the application got into one of the Visual Studio configuration files, and was not fixed. I deleted the folders .vs and x64, the former requiring you to close the application, then did a full rebuild, but still got the errors. It thus appears that at least one of the XML configuration files is corrupted. Rather than trying to find the error, it is easier to just copy the files over to a new solution and discard the old one. This will save a lot of time.
If anybody else has had a similar problem I would be interested to know.
